# VHDL if statement - Syntax error near text

Tags: vhdl

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

I get a error on the comment line. Saying syntax error near text. I tried to change from both binary to hex numbers, but keep getting the same error.
Were the errors are is comment selected.

This are the errors:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at MAL.vhd(26) near text
>   Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at MAL.vhd(26) near text "";  expecting "then"
>   Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at MAL.vhd(26) near text ­ 
>   Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at MAL.vhd(26) near text ¬
>   Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at MAL.vhd(29) near text "else";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("else" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement
>   Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at MAL.vhd(31) near text "if";  expecting "process"

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY MAL IS
    PORT (
        clk_50 : IN std_logic;
        pulse_out : OUT std_logic
    );
END MAL;

ARCHITECTURE behave OF MAL IS
    SIGNAL pulse : std_logic;
    SIGNAL counter : std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    PROCESS (clk_50) IS
    BEGIN
        pulse <= '0';
        -- if counter = ‭x"‭C34F‬"‬ then
        -- counter <= (others => '0');
        pulse <= '1';
        -- else
        counter <= counter + 1;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

    --output
    pulse_out <= pulse;

END ARCHITECTURE behave;
```

Comment: Please include the error message, and update the source code to include line number in a comment, like `-- Line 27` since the `27 if` is definitely a syntax error :-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Its is now changed. I could not find were to include the line number in Quartus. Do you know where?

Comment: This code is not what generated those errors. You commented out "else", and it is still in the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some illegal character in there. Remove line 27 and re-write it and you should be ok.

Comment: Should i re-write the variable name or the Hex number?

Comment: Remove everything to get rid of that hidden character and then re-write the entire line just like you intended it to be: if counter = ‭x"‭C34F‬"‬ then

Comment: @remivass: If this is the answer for your question, then remember to accept it by clicking the check mark, as described in [accepted-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). See more in [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Which line is line 27 and why is it a problem? Counting shows the 27th line in the question is a blank line before the line with the comment `--output`. On the other hand line 20 (commented out) contains at least one non-ISO-8859-1 character and line 25 shows the error attributed to line 31 in the questions error messages.